# Unable to delete the core storage local volume group

Tags: macos, partition

Currently, I'm trying to delete one of my partitions but for some reason it's giving me this issue:

[image]

Does anyone know how I could go about clearing this?

Answer (score 8):

Disk Utility won’t let you erase or repartition an encrypted CoreStorage volume until you unlock or decrypt. This can be an issue for a CoreStorage volume that will not let you either unlock or decrypt.

To help with this, the `diskutil` tool provides a way to quickly delete CoreStorage volumes. This includes the ability to erase encrypted CoreStorage volumes without first decrypting or unlocking them.

To do this, first run the following command:

```
diskutil cs list
```

This will give you with a list of the CoreStorage volumes on your system. Unless you have a Fusion drive or multiple encrypted drives, your encrypted drive should be the only one listed.

[image]

In the listing, you will want to select and copy the **Logical Volume Group** (LVG) alphanumeric UUID for your CoreStorage volume. The LVG should be the first UUID listed and it’s the one we want to delete.

Next, run the following command:

```
diskutil cs delete UUID_here
```

[image]

This will delete your CoreStorage volume and reformat it as an unencrypted HFS+ volume.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my problem when I got the following error in Disk Utility in 10.12 Sierra: `Unable to delete the Core Storage logical volume.` (slightly different error message)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to wipe it, select Macintosh HD 2 and then repartition that drive. If you want to use terminal to understand the deeper structure and selectively delete things, [Rich's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210282/5472) is the best choice.

In your special case, it looks like you can wipe he entire volume and not affect or lose other data. That isn't always the case so command line is needed in that more general situation.